# Kindle Fire MediaPlayer volume loud relative to SoundPool

Tags: android, audio, kindle-fire

I have an app that uses `SoundPool` for sound effects, and `MediaPlayer` for ambient noise.

On every other device I've tested it on, the relative volumes are good, but on the kindle fire (HDX 7 3rd gen) the ambient noise from `MediaPlayer` is so loud it drowns out the sound effects from `SoundPool`.

This happens with or without head phones.

Is there some way to know the relative volumes of `MediaPlayer` and `SoundPool`?